# Changing motion clips via script in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, animation, character

is there a way in Unity to access the Motion clip of an Animator State and change it at runtime via script? I am trying to do a character shop in my 2D game. My idea is, when i click a GUI button it would just select different motion clips but the states would stay the same. It's just a simple Jump and Idle state, parameters dont change. I just want to feed in different animation clips for different characters.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you would do this via the Mechanim state machine.  Create a transition and set it to change via a Trigger.

[image]

Doing it this way, when you want to swap animation states, you simply do this:

```
Animator.SetTrigger ("Swap");
```

If you want to set the Animator Motion directly, it is a little more complicated.  You will need to create Animation Controllers, and then swap them using the [AnimatorOverrideController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html).

Comment: I used the AnimatorOverrideController and it works! Thank you.